# how can i access database inside android appication to my computer

Tags: android, sql, database, android-sqlite, android-database

I am developing an app in our college for an event.i wanted to get the value of a variable in that app after every round  from all the phones to my computer.How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways but one way

1. Create a JSON object containing data you want to store on database.
2. Create mysql database in your computer, i use Wamp Server or any of
   your choice
3. Write PHP code with which you can interact with your
   database (read/write on your database) (read JSON object sent by app
   and inreturn Send JSON responce you create in php)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to browse information in database then  you can use sqlite master pro app for android but your phone must be rooted. If you want to send database info to computer(server) then you need to write webservice in php or in other language